# Perl opening file handle in append mode to read

Tags: perl

I have a text file where I have to read the content and append to it. i.e. make a copy of the file and append to it. I wrote the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line;
open FILL, ">> fred"
    or warn "Cannot open : $!";
while(<FILL>){
   # s/^Author:.*/Author: Randal L. Schwartz/;
   # s/^Phone:.*\n//;
   # s/^Date:.*/Date: $date/;
    $line.=$_;
    print $line;
}
select FILL;
print $line;
```

But it doesn't enter the while loop at all and when I open a filehandle for the same file in read mode and select the file handle in append mode to print it works.

Input :

```
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Size: 21k
Status: Final beta
```

Output :

```
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Size: 21k
Status: Final beta
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Size: 21k
Status: Final beta
```

This program works correctly

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line;
open FIL, "fred"
    or warn "Cannot open : $!";
open FILL, ">> fred"
    or warn "Cannot open : $!";
while(<FIL>){
   # s/^Author:.*/Author: Randal L. Schwartz/;
   # s/^Phone:.*\n//;
   # s/^Date:.*/Date: $date/;
    $line.=$_;
    print $line;
}
select FILL;
print $line;
```

It appends correctly in file but the terminal output is

```
Program name: granite
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Size: 21k
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Size: 21k
Status: Final beta
Program name: granite
Author: Gilbert Bates
Company: RockSoft
Department: R&D
Phone: +1 503 555-0095
Date: Tues March 9, 2004
Version: 2.1
Size: 21k
Status: Final beta
```

Why does it print so many times?

Comment: `+>>` and seek to beginning of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$line` is the variable in which you accumulate everything read so far. So within the loop, you probably wanted to do

```
print $_;
```

or just

```
print;
```

instead of

```
print $line;
```

To answer your original question... You will want to open the file in both read and write (append) mode.

```
open FILL, '>>+', 'fred';
```

(Please don't use the 2-argument version of `open`. It's unsafe.)

But this places the file pointer at the end of the file, so you'll have to do a

```
seek FILL, 0, 0;
```

before reading. Since you read before writing, it makes no difference whether or not you open the file in append mode.

You should even be able to add another `seek` after reading the file, but I am not sure whether this is going to be portable across Unix and Windows.

Comment: Thanks I got it. But I want to use the filehandle in append mode for reading too. If I read a filehandle in append mode it doesn't enter the loop at all @hillu